# Update React state by using a dynamic path name

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to dynamically update my formData based on a (nested) path.

I've got the following formData state

```
const [formData, setFormData] = useState({ 
    profile: {
        first_name: '',
        last_name: '',
        date_of_birth: '',
        phone: ''
    },
    mandate: {
        type: 'opt_in'
    },
    payment: {
        iban: '',
        payment_type: ''
    }
});
```

Example of a input field

```
<input type="text" name="profile.first_name" value={formData.profile.first_name} onChange={handleChange} />
```

In my handleChange I've split the path into parts but now I'm stuck. How can I loop through this parts, copy the state in an controlled way and update the correct property

```
const handleChange = (e) => {
    const parts = e.target.name.split('.');
    const newValue = e.target.value;

    const currentValues = { ...formData };

    const updatedValues = currentValues // How to deeply update the state?

    setFormData(updatedValues);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You would need to carry over the `formData` state by using `(curr) =>` callback inside your state setter. Then we spread along the form and overwrite the fields by writing them last.

**Solution 1**

In case that your path always is of type `key.subkey` this would be a solution:

```
  const handleChange = (e) => {
    const parts = e.target.name.split(".");
    const newValue = e.target.value;

    setFormData((curr) => ({
      ...curr,
      [parts[0]]: {
        ...curr[parts[0]],
        [parts[1]]: newValue,
      },
    }));
  };
```

**Solution 2**

If you want to set `newValue` regardless of the depth you can make use of this `handleChange` function.

The `setValue` function will create keys that don't exist and overwrite existing ones.

```
  const handleChange = (e) => {
    const setValue = (object, path, value) => {
      const fullPath = path.split("."),
        way = fullPath.slice(),
        last = way.pop();

      way.reduce((obj, next) => (obj[next] = obj[next] || {}), object)[last] =
        value;
    };

    const parts = e.target.name.split(".");
    const newValue = e.target.value;

    setFormData((curr) => {
      setValue(curr, parts, newValue);
      return curr;
    });
  };
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer but this is not dynamic. It only goes two deep. If I need something like address.geolocation.longitude it will fail

Comment: I made an edit with another solution, does this fit your needs?

Answer (score 1):

As far as possible, you should avoid nesting states.
The flatter the structure, the easier and better it is to understand and debug the code.

However there are times when it is unavoidable in which case as @sm3sher answered, you can do deep copy.

It is redundant, lots of code and not easy to extract logic into a reusable function.
You can use a library called Immer to update state writing mutable logic.
Read more: https://beta.reactjs.org/learn/choosing-the-state-structure#avoid-deeply-nested-state

Comment: I agree that it is much better using flat structures as much as possible.